# Shortcode to insert the "Registration Form" in other page?

Tags: user-registration

I'm trying to insert the "Registration Form" in a page using this shortcode
[wp-form-registration]but it doesn't work.

I just need to show the Registration form in a page in the frontend.

This is the code to create the shortcode:

```
function print_form_registration($atts, $content = null) { 
     return wp_register(); 
} 
add_shortcode('wp-form-registration', 'print_form_registration');
```

Comment: That's not a standard WordPress shortcode. Are you using a plugin? You should ask the author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just added the code which creates the shortcode.

Comment: Did you read the documenation for `wp_register()` that function shows a link. Is *that* appearing?

Comment: What are you adding a registration for? Is it 'just any' registration for, - because in that case, then I would recommend you'd just use some formular-plugin (like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ or https://www.gravityforms.com/ ). This will then send you an email with, whenever people fill it out. - But if you're after something that registers the user at your WordPress-installation, then I'd use a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/ (instructions are in the 'Installation'-tab).

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes it does, I get this link http://example.com/wp-admin/
I need to put the "registration form" instead. Can you give a clue me to start with this?

Comment: WordPress doesn't have a function for outputting a registration form. If that's what you need help with please refer to previous questions on the topic.